# Django Ajax POST request: Internal server error

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django, django-views

Note that I'm a big noob in AJAX, since I started recently.
I'm using Django 2.0 and Python.
I'm trying to return a list of not compatible options under the form of an array.

**Here is my model :**

```
class Door(models.Model) :
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default='119.99')
    not_comp_options = models.ManyToManyField(Option)
```

**Here is my js template:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/get_not_compat_options/" + door_id,
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function()
    {
        console.log(data.onct)
    } 
})
```

**Here is my urls:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Other url patterns
    path('get_not_compat_options', views.get_not_compat_options, name="get_not_compat_options")
]
```

**Here is my views:**

```
def get_not_compat_options(request, door_id) :
    onct = []
    door = get_object_or_404(Door, id=door_id)
    not_compat_options = door.not_comp_options
    for option in not_comp_options.all() :
        onct.append(option.name)
    data.append({"onct": onct})
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Unfortunately, in the browser console, I get an error saying: `500 (Internal Server Error)`
PS: If that could help, I'm using Nginx and gunicorn for my server.

Comment: Can you post your error log so we can have a better understanding of what is going wrong?

Comment: You should see the Python server's log for the traceback.

Comment: I get `jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST http://178.128.42.122/shop/get_not_compat_options/14 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Where do I see that

Comment: Do you get the data successfully into view

Comment: You need to look in your browser's dev tools for the full error sent by the server.

Comment: It is also rather strange to do this with a POST request. Since no data changes, and no parameters are transferred, a GET makes more sense.

Comment: I get the same error with GET

Comment: @FantasmoClone27: yes, that is not supprisingly, I'm only saying that this does not really follow the REST guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `data.append()` without defining data first.

Perhaps you want either

```
data = [{"onct": onct}]
```

or

```
data = {"onct": onct}
```

Comment: Also a switch between `not_compat_options` and `not_comp_options`.

Comment: csrf token missing

Comment: There are as far as I can see, no other dictionaries: only one, and the other are `.name`s, which seems to suggest that those are strings.

Comment: @Wariored I don't think CSRF is the issue here - I would expect to see status code 403 instead of 500.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I misread the loop before, I've changed my suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Alasdair

Answer (score 0):

There are some strange things here:

1. you make a POST request, but the view has no *side-effects*, nor does the POST transfers any data. In that case a GET makes more sense;
2. based on the `success` handle, it looks like the result should be a dictionary with a key `onct`; and
3. The url in `urls.py` does not contain the `door_id` parameter.

By using `.values_list(..)` in the query, we can also save a bit on database bandwidth, and furthermore make the view more elegant:

```
def get_not_compat_options(request, door_id):
    door = get_object_or_404(Door, id=door_id)
    not_compat_options = door.not_comp_options
    data = {'onct': list(not_comp_options.all().values_list('name', flat=True))}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

and the AJAX request then could look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/get_not_compat_options/" + door_id,
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function()
    {
        console.log(data.onct)
    } 
})
```

Furthermore the `urls.py` shoudl probably look like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Other url patterns
    path('get_not_compat_options/<int:door_id>', views.get_not_compat_options, name="get_not_compat_options")
]
```

Since otherwise this `path(..)` can not accept an `door_id`.